# How to create a dictionary of word parts from the words that start and end with the same letter

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to write a script - read_dict(dictionary) - that takes a .txt file as argument and gives a dictionary of word parts of every word in the file. The parts are the first and last letter of every word, and the remaining letters. For example if the file is as following:

```
===dictionary.txt===
quack  qk
quick qk
going gg
gathering gg
quirk qk
quicken qn
```

output should be :

> { 'qk' : {'uac', 'uic'}, 'gg' : {'oin', 'atherin'}, 'qn' : {'uicke' }}

I wrote this:

```
def outside(word):
    a = word.strip()[0]
    b = word.strip()[-1]
    out_word = a + b
    return out_word


def inside(word):
    a = word.strip()[1:-1]
    return a


def read_dict(dictionary):
    a = {}
    with open(dictionary, 'r') as text:
        data = text.readlines()
        for i in data:
            a[outside(i)] = inside(i)
    return a
```

But my output is:

> { 'qk' : 'uac', 'gg' : 'oin', 'qn' : 'uicke'}

It only saves the first words. I also couldn't find a way to gather all the inside(word)s with the same letters outside in a set, then adding them to a dictionary with the appropriate key such as 'qk'.

Comment: You are looking for `collections.defaultdict`.

Comment: you want to append when reading the dictionary. `a[outside(i)].append(inside(i))`. Of course you will have to first check if the key exist, if not do `a[outside(i)] =[inside(i)]` so it's initialized for the next time the key is seen¨

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Ch3steR says, this can be easily achieved with [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). Modify your code to this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def read_dict(dictionary):
    a = defaultdict(set)
    with open(dictionary, 'r') as text:
        data = text.readlines()
        for i in data:
            a[outside(i)].add(inside(i))
    return a
```

If you do not want to use any external libraries, you can do:

```
def read_dict(dictionary):
    a = {}
    with open(dictionary, 'r') as text:
        data = text.readlines()
        for i in data:
            key = outside(i)
            if key in a:
                a[key].add(inside(i))
            else:
                a[key] = {inside(i)}
    return a
```

By comparing the two code snippets you also get an idea what `collections.defaultdict` does and how it allows you to write less code.

Comment: Thanks for the creds. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the detailed explanation.

Comment: @arthionne somehow I missed that. Check the edit. You can use `defaultdict` with anything that can hold values in a *normal* dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `a[outside(i)]` a list and append each new item to it, instead of just overwriting it each time you find a new one.

Also, why do you grab the 1st and last letters of the word, when you already have those in the file for you?

```
def read_dict(dictionary):
    a = {}

    with open(dictionary, 'r') as text:
        data = text.readlines()
        value, key = data.split(' ')

        if key not in a:
            a[key] = []

        a[key].append(value[1:-1])

    return a
```

Comment: It would probably be better to do `key, value, *_ = data.split(' ')` to avoid using `word[1]` 3 times.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Thanks.  That is definitely nicer looking :)